# FOOTER APPEARS VERTICAL ON WEBSITE but displays correctly on my VScode live server. I need making the content in my footer display as Row

Tags: html, css, web, wordpress-theming, footer

HTML For footer

```
  `<strike> <div class= "footer2">   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer-col-1">
                <h3>Download Our App</h3>
                <p>Download App for Android and ios mobile phone.</p>
                <div class="app-logo">
                    <img src="https://blah blah.png">
                    <img src="https://blah blah.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-col-2">
                <img src="https://blah blah.png">
                <p>We're Committed To Helping You Become The<br>Best Version Of Yourself</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-col-3">
                <h3>USEFUL LINKS</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>PASSIVE INCOME</li>
                    <li>SIDE HUSTLES</li>
                    <li>DISCOVERIES</li>
                    <li>WORKSPACE</li>           
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-col-4">
                <h3>GET IN TOUCH</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li> <img src="https:blah blah.png">730 3rd Ave NY 10017, USA</li>
                    <li> <img src="https:blah blahs.png">talk2us@blah blah.com</li>
                    <li>Return Policy</li>
                    <li>Contact Us</li>                      
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
            <hr>
            <p class="copyright">Copyright 2021 - blah blah </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </strike>`
```

CSS for footer

```
 `<strike> .footer2{
              background: #000;
              color: #8a8a8a;
              font-size: 14px;
              padding: 60px 0 20 px;
           }
           .footer2 p{
              color: #8a8a8a;
           }
           .footer2 h3{
              color:#fff;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
           }
           .footer-col-1, .footer-col-2, .footer-col-3, .footer-col-4{
              min-width: 250px;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
           }
           .footer-col-1{
              flex-basis: 30%;
           }
           .footer-col-2{
              flex: 1;
              text-align: center;
          }
          .footer-col-2 img{
             width: 180px;
             margin-bottom: 20px;
          }
          .footer-col-3, .footer-col-4{
             flex-basis: 12%;
             text-align: center;
          }
          .ul{
              list-style-type: none;
          }
           </strike>`
```

FOOTER APPEARS VERTICAL ON WEBSITE but displays correctly on my VScode live server. I need making the content in my footer display as Row

I am new to html and css coding, I tried changing the html and css many different ways but still the same issue sorry for the long post. I just tried to explain the problem as best as possible. Thanks a lot.